# ajax very slow in IE 8 but very fast in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax

There are a lot of similar posts but nothing quite fit my need. So I am forced create a post.

List of names are displayed on a jsp page. When you hover over a name, I do an ajax call to display the details for that name in a tooltip popup.

The users will be using IE8. It takes approximately about 5 seconds to do this simple thing in IE8 where as in Firefox and chrome it happens instantly.

What I have also noticed is that as the numbers of name displayed increases or decreases, the response time also does the same in IE8.

How can I make it faster in IE8?

jsp page

```
<td onmouseover ="showDetails('${origin }')">
    <a href="#"><c:out value="${origin}"></c:out><span id="info"></span></a> 
</td>
```

javascript function

```
function showDetails(stop){
    var xmlHttpRequest; 
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpRequest.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", "showStopsInfoPopup.do?stop="+stop, true);
    xmlHttpRequest.send();
}
```

Comment: Why do you use the jQuery tag if you're not using any jQuery code? If you are using jQuery, just use the [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.

Comment: I apologize. I am relatively new to ajax. So I thought someone who would know jquery would also know about this issue. When I googled this problem, it seemed a lot of people who had similar problems were using jquery.

Comment: The latency might actually be due to innerHTML, not the ajax request. I'd suggest that you time them separately.

Comment: @Christophe can you tell me of a way to time them separately? I tried the answers provided below by user "stacktrace" which I believe is to time the request and I received an alert box with "Nan milliseconds" message.

Comment: Use your preferred browser's developer tools, they will tell you a lot about the timeline and network activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
function showDetails(stop){
    var t1 = new Date().getTime();
    var xmlHttpRequest; 
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpRequest.status == 200){
            alert("Call took " + (new Date().getTime() - t1) + " milliseconds");
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", "showStopsInfoPopup.do?stop="+stop, true);
    xmlHttpRequest.send();
}
```

You'll probably see that the call is equally fast, but it's the subsequent rendering of the response that is slow in IE8.

If you confirm that, the question then is about what's in the responseText.

Comment: I did the above and I get a alert box with message "Nan milliseconds"

Comment: In the response text is a string which is usually less than 20 characters long.

Comment: Edited the time calculation part, try again.

Comment: This is the message I get " Call took 5696 milliseconds". Tried it few times, it's mostly around 5000 milliseconds

Comment: Does that time vary between IE8 and Chrome? I think 5 seconds is pretty slow for ajax type activity..

Comment: Yes it does. It's about 100 ms in firefox

Answer (score 2):

Instead:

```
xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpRequest.status == 200){
        alert("Call took " + new Date().getTime() - t1 + " milliseconds");
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
    }
}
xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", "showStopsInfoPopup.do?stop="+stop, true);
xmlHttpRequest.send();
```

try this:

```
xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", "showStopsInfoPopup.do?stop="+stop, true);
xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpRequest.status == 200){
        alert("Call took " + new Date().getTime() - t1 + " milliseconds");
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
    }
}
xmlHttpRequest.send(null);
```

**Fix new Date**

In your code lacked parentheses (Remember to separate `Mathematics` of `Strings`). Try:

```
xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", "showStopsInfoPopup.do?stop="+stop, true);
xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpRequest.status == 200){
        alert("Call took " + (new Date().getTime() - t1) + " milliseconds");
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
    }
}
xmlHttpRequest.send(null);
```

---

**Test**
Ajax Request:

```
<div id="info"></div>
<script>var xhr, t1;
if(window.ActiveXObject){
    try { xhr=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }catch(e){
        try { xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }catch(e){}
    }
} else if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
}

xhr.open("GET", "teste.php", true);

t1 = new Date().getTime();//I start the timer that point to prevent the previous functions affect the end result

xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Call took " + (new Date().getTime() - t1) + " milliseconds";
    }
}
xhr.send(null);
</script>
```

**php (teste.php):**

```
<?php
sleep(5);
echo 'ok';
?>
```

**results:**

- IE8: 5004 milliseconds
- Chorme: 5005 milliseconds
- Firefox: 5014 milliseconds
- IE7: 5023 milliseconds
- IE6: 5053 milliseconds

After the tests, concludes that perhaps something on the side of the server-side, to be more exact in your PHP.

Comment: I get an alert box with message "Nan milliseconds"

Comment: The message says about "Call took 5696 milliseconds". It's usually around 5000 milliseconds.

Comment: And before you use my code, how many milliseconds was returning in IE?

Comment: it took the same milliseconds

Comment: It may be a matter of server-side and not client-side, I'm testing on my computer speeds, soon I'll be back with the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jquery:

```
function showDetails(stop) {
  $('#info').load("showStopsInfoPopup.do?stop=" + stop);
}
```

Comment: Tried this. It did shave off about 2 seconds from the total time. But it's still taking around 3 seconds.